# What are the options for handling flags and attributes in a REST API?

Tags: http, api, rest

Let's say you have a complex resource in a REST API.  You have several one-to-many flags and attributes on this resource (i.e., a user may have given the resource a rating of 1 to 5 or the user may have 'liked' the resource or marked it as spam or ignored it or caused some other state to be set).

Some suggestions have been made on the best way to represent this in a resource-centric architecture, but so far none of them have really made me happy.  So let's crowd-source this; which variants do you find easiest to understand?  Which variants haven't we thought of?  Assume an OAuth-based API and everything here is done in the context of the currently authorized user.

- Boolean Flags

  - Variant 1:

    ```
    GET /resource/{id}/muted
    POST /resource/{id}/muted BODY:true
    POST /resource/{id}/muted BODY:false
    ```
  - Variant 2:

    ```
    GET /resource/{id}/muted
    PUT /resource/{id}/muted BODY:true
    DELETE /resource/{id}/muted
    ```
  - Variant 3:

    ```
    GET /resource/{id}/attributes
    POST /resource/{id}/attributes BODY:muted=true
    POST /resource/{id}/attributes BODY:muted=false
    ```
  - Variant 4:

    ```
    GET /resource/{id}/muted
    POST /resource/{id}/mute
    POST /resource/{id}/unmute
    ```
- Attributes

  - Variant 1

    ```
    GET /resource/{id}/rating
    POST /resource/{id}/rating BODY:4
    ```
  - Variant 2:

    ```
    GET /resource/{id}/rating
    PUT /resource/{id}/rating BODY:4
    DELETE /resource/{id}/rating
    ```
  - Variant 3:

    ```
    GET /resource/{id}/attributes
    POST /resource/{id}/attributes BODY:rating=4
    POST /resource/{id}/attributes BODY:rating=
    ```

Thoughts?  Suggestions?  How have other APIs handled this?  How have you handled it?  Have you found that design issues like this have had significant effects on developer happiness or the ease-of-use of your APIs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Roy's dissertation](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm):

> a uniform interface degrades efficiency, since information is transferred in a standardized form rather than one which is specific to an application's needs. The REST interface is designed to be efficient for large-grain hypermedia data transfer

So you need a variant 5 which works for both flags and other attributes:

```
GET /resource/{id}/  BODY:{muted: false, like: false, rating: 2, ignored: true}
POST /resource/{id}/ BODY:{muted: true, like: false, rating: 2, ignored: true}
POST /resource/{id}/ BODY:{muted: false, like: false, rating: 2, ignored: true}
```

One big reason is that most of a RESTful HTTP application's efficiency comes from caching, and that works best when its artifacts are at as large a grain as possible, and when its data is reachable at as few identifiers as possible. If you expose the 'muted' flag at both `/resource/{id}/` and `/resource/{id}/muted`, then you have a cache invalidation problem. If you expose it only at `/resource/{id}/`, then you don't.

If you are designing an application that aims for efficiency via small payloads, then you cannot benefit from large grain caching, and the REST architectural style is not appropriate for your app. HTTP probably isn't either, but I can understand how someone might be stuck with that in today's market.

Comment: Well, that's actually Variant 3, but with an `application/json` payload instead of a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` payload.  Same basic idea, but `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is better suited to partial updates of the resource.

Comment: Also, because everything is behind OAuth, the caching argument is a little weaker than usual.  The client on the receiving end can cache, and certainly that cache would be more efficient with a larger resource.  However, from a developer perspective, 95+% will only mutate one attribute at a time and no assumption can be made that the body of the data you send to the server will match what you receive if you immediately make a `GET`.  This probably eliminates `PUT` as an option right there, and by extension, `DELETE`.  I'm happy with that, because that was my least favorite solution.

Comment: As for cache invalidation, it's pretty safe to say that the application in question can only minimize that issue, not eliminate it.  Such is life at scale.

Comment: Well, if you're not going to use the uniform interface, caching, or statelessness (and I assume you're ignoring the hypermedia, as well) than I'd say whatever API you're looking to design is not a REST one. Sounds like RPC would be a better choice.

Comment: Shouldn't the last two POSTs actually be PUTs?

Answer (score 0):

I like Variant 3 if I can provide a bunch at once -- otherwise, I'm indifferent between 1 and 3.

And, definitely nothing that uses DELETE.

Comment: Yes, I should have made it more clear that Variant 3 was `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.